# How can the bin width be set for a histogram where the "Probability" option is used?

Tags: histograms

How can a histogram be created when the "Probability" option is used, and a specified bin width is needed?

In the example below, I am trying to set the bin width to 1, but Mathematica throws an error:

```
 Histogram[data, Automatic, "Probability", {1}]
```

Comment: Try "PDF"......

Comment: I thought PDF was exclusively for situations where the distribution is known. I am using data...

Comment: The [docs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Histogram.html) say `Histogram[data,bspec,hspec]`, where `bspec` is the bin width specification, and `hspec` – bin height.

Comment: The histogram is a bit outdated.  Try `SmoothHistogram` or `SmoothKernelDistribution`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

`Histogram[data, {x}, "Probability"];` x is your bin size.